# SWT Table - How to change columns width using keyboard only?

Tags: user-interface, swt, accessibility

I am using SWT tables in my project and there are few columns which are having longer strings which are not completely visible by default (for ex. path to a file location). Though I have tooltip to show the content and using mouse we can increase the column width to see the complete value.

Is there a way to do it with only keyboard usage?

Note: This question is more related to accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on my experience under windows. It can be different for other OS.

I'm afraid that there's no keyboard-only default way to adjust the size or reorder the column in a table, tree view or list view.
This is true not only with SWT but also with all other frameworks based on native win32 such as wxWidgets.

You must provide a keyboard-only way to resize and reorder columns yourself. here are a few ideas implemented by some applications:

- Provide an option somewhere in the application that opens a dialog box with a checkbox list of the different columns. Ctrl+Up/Down to swap two items. Check/uncheck an item with spacebar to make the column visible or invisible.
- Make the headers focusable. Use Shift+Left/Right to resize, Ctrl+Left/Right to swap two columns. Application key / Shift+10 opens a context menu where you can check/uncheck columns to show/hide and an option to open the column selection dialog box.

Some screen readers allow to do it by simulating mouse operation in some way. For example, use Jaws cursor, click lock on a header, release lock on the header to swap with.
But it's quite complicated, not always reliable, and thus very rarely actually used.

This is a very good question. I would be happy to give 100 rep to someone giving an answer being for windows and:

- generic, working by default, everywhere or in most cases
- Independant from screen readers (Jaws, NVDA, etc.) and techniques that simulates the mouse with keyboard (mouse keys)

Unfortunately, I don't think it exists.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It would be great if you could point me to any document or web link for learning more about SWT and accessibility. We have many issues related to accessibility in our project. Most of them are related to SWT features. For example: table content is not read properly, graph selection not working properly etc. Also, if there is any tutorial which helps in creating new shortcuts that would also be helpful.